# Decompose list into lists of successive subsequences

Tags: list, prolog

I am really sorry for previous question, it's my first time post question on this website and I really didn't know I shouldn't post quesion like that.
It was my first time using prolog. Actually I spent more than 5 hours on this question but still cannot fully solve it, I tried to tear this question apart and here is what remain to be solved:

How to put the successive increasing whole numbers into a sublist in origin list.

eg. [3,5,1,2,3,7,8,2] to [3,5,[1,2,3],[7,8],2]

Here is what I wrote, can someone tell me how to fix the code? Thanks.

```
% empty List
chop_up([], []).

% single item list
chop_up([X], [X]).

% continue if the first number is not part of a sequence
chop_up(List, NewList):-
    List = [First | Tail],
    Tail = [Second | _],
    First =\= Second - 1,
    chop_up(Tail, NewList2),
    NewList = [First | NewList2].

% if it is part of a sequence
chop_up(List, NewList):-
    List = [First | Tail],
    Tail = [Second | Tail2],
    First is Second - 1,
    chop_up(Tail, NewList2),
    NewList = [[First] | NewList2].
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXmHa.jpg)

Comment: Okay, that is a nice assignment. Do you also have a question?

Comment: Welcome! Please don't just copy and paste your homework here, show us what you tried and explain what exactly you have trouble with. There are some guidelines on asking good questions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking .

Comment: A pasted homework question is not likely to be answered. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: At least pretend to try and solve the problem, I'm happy to help people who try. This problem is so ridiculously easy to solve, I just can't bring myself to bother and write a program. I mean really? For [N1, N2, N3] check if N1 + 1 equals N2 and do something if it is and do something else if it isn't.

Comment: Above is my question, please take a look, thanks. @anothernode @Johan@G_V

Comment: @Isabelle Newbie

Comment: @CodeFish That's much better already. You can further improve the question by including the program output as text in the question instead of a linked image. Your aim should be to make it as easy as possible for others to understand your specific problem. That way you maximize the chances of receiving a helpful answer.

Comment: Thank you for your useful advice. Since this question is alredy been solved, I may not update the program output as text for this question, but I'll definitely do it next time.@anothernode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for updating your question to show us what you tried!

Like all Prolog beginners, you are trying to do too much at once. This is normal! But you have to learn and get used to a way of thinking that is different from other programming languages. Almost always you have to decompose your problem into several subproblems that you then put together to get the final program.

So let's try to solve only one part of the problem first: Given a nonempty list, decompose it into successive elements *at the front* and into all the remaining elements. That is, we want something like this:

```
?- list_successive_rest([1, 2, 4, 3], Succ, Rest).
Succ = [1, 2],
Rest = [4, 3] .
```

If we can write this definition, then we should be able to iterate over the `Rest` to chop it up further.

Here is a definition of `list_successive_rest/3`. Note how it follows the structure of your attempt for `chop_up/2`, but it's shorter and simpler because we only look at a successive prefix of the list, not all of the list at once:

```
list_successive_rest([X], [X], []).
list_successive_rest([A, B | Xs], [A], [B | Xs]) :-
    A + 1 =\= B.
list_successive_rest([A, B | Xs], [A | Successive], Rest) :-
    A + 1 =:= B,
    list_successive_rest([B | Xs], Successive, Rest).
```

(This is also simpler than your version because I match lists of at least two elements as `[A, B | Xs]` rather than `[A | Tail]` and `Tail = [B | Tail2]`. It's a good idea to get used to this syntax.)

We can call this successively to decompose a list into successive parts:

```
?- list_successive_rest([1, 2, 4, 3], Succ, Rest), list_successive_rest(Rest, Succ2, Rest2), list_successive_rest(Rest2, Succ3, Rest3).
Succ = [1, 2],
Rest = [4, 3],
Succ2 = [4],
Rest2 = Succ3, Succ3 = [3],
Rest3 = [] ;
false.
```

Defining `chop_up/2` is now easy by using the above predicate to peel off successive prefixes of the list iteratively:

```
chop_up([], []).
chop_up(List, [Succ | Chopped]) :-
    list_successive_rest(List, Succ, Rest),
    chop_up(Rest, Chopped).
```

Note that `chop_up/2` is recursive, and it uses `list_successive_rest/3`, which is recursive as well. Trying to write all this in *one* recursive predicate would be harder and lead to less readable code.

Let's try the above test, and your test case:

```
?- chop_up([1, 2, 4, 3], Chopped).
Chopped = [[1, 2], [4], [3]] ;
false.

?- chop_up([3,5,1,2,3,7,8,2], Chopped).
Chopped = [[3], [5], [1, 2, 3], [7, 8], [2]] ;
false.
```

This doesn't actually produce the exact format you wanted: Singleton elements are singleton lists rather than "naked" members of the outer list. I think this is better this way, but your teacher may disagree. In that case, changing this small detail is an exercise for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! As a beginner, I learnt a lot from your solution which helps me get a deeper understanding of prolog. Hope you can help more people:) @Isabelle Newbie

Answer (score 3):

I conseived much more elegant way with DCG!

```
chunk_list([])-->[].
chunk_list([C|Rest])-->chunk(C),chunk_list(Rest).

chunk(Ret)-->[First],consecutive(First,Last),{First=:=Last->Ret is First;Ret = [First,Last]}.

consecutive(Prev,Last)-->[Current],{Current is Prev+1},consecutive(Current,Last).
consecutive(Prev,Prev)-->[].
```

Test:

```
 ?- phrase(chunk_list(R),[1,2,3,6,7,3,3,2,3,4,6],[]).
R = [[1, 3], [6, 7], 3, 3, [2, 4], 6]
```

maybe it could be reversible with more lavor.
I.E. convert [[1, 3], [6, 7], 3, 3, [2, 4], 6] into [1,2,3,6,7,3,3,2,3,4,6]

Answer (score 1):

I also tried for my prolog training.
terrible program but does work anyway.
I tested this in ECLiPSe but it will work with few modification in other environment(may be only deleting `:-lib(listut)`)

call like this:

```
chunk([4,5,6,3,4,4,57,3,4,5,7,2,3,4,5,7,7,54,3],Ret).
```

Program:

```
:-lib(listut).

chunk(List,Ans):-
    chunk_sub(List,0,[],List1),
    first_and_lasts(List1,Ans),
    !.


chunk_sub([],_,Ret,Reverse):-reverse(Ret,Reverse),!.
chunk_sub([Current|Rest],Prev,[NowList|RetRest],Ret):-
    Current =:= Prev+1,
    append(NowList,[Current],NextList),
    chunk_sub(Rest,Current,[NextList|RetRest],Ret).
chunk_sub([Current|Rest],_,NowList,Ret):-
    chunk_sub(Rest,Current,[[Current]|NowList],Ret).

first_and_lasts([],[]):-!.
first_and_lasts([FirstList|RestLists],[Converted|RestRet]):-
    length(FirstList,Len),
    (
        Len=:=1->
        ([OneElem]=FirstList,Converted=OneElem);
        (
            nth1(1,FirstList,Smallest),
            nth1(Len,FirstList,Biggest),
            Converted=[Smallest,Biggest]
        )
    ),
    first_and_lasts(RestLists,RestRet).
```

Comment: When you try: `?- chunk(X, Y).`, then you only get a single solution: `X = Y, Y = [].` Maybe it is possible to generalize this so that it can also *generate* answers?

Comment: I didn't assume the case first parameter is not ground in this code. Do you mean 'generalize' as 'working bidirectionaly'? I tried it in DCG version.

Comment: Bidirectionality is definitely a part of this. But there are more than 2 directions: We can ask the most general query, where *both* arguments are variables. It would be awesome if all possible answers were generated in this case!

Comment: What shoud this program output when try '?-chunk(X,Y) ' ,do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I did it!
this is reversible(generalized) version.This program works cleverly.
It was very fun developing this.

Code:

```
chunk_list([])-->[],!.
chunk_list([Chunk|Rest])-->chunk(Chunk),!,chunk_list(Rest).

chunk([First,Last])-->sequence([First,Last]),{First<Last}. % sequence
chunk(Val)-->sequence([Val,Val]).               % isolated number

sequence([First,Last])-->
                {(number(First),number(Last))->First<Last;true},
                [First],
                {succ(First,Second)},sequence([Second,Last]).
sequence([Val,Val])-->[Val].
```

Test:

```
[eclipse 4]: phrase(chunk_list([2,[2,6],[3,5],3,7,[1,3]]),Ret).

Ret = [2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 3, 7, 1, 2, 3]
Yes (0.00s cpu)

[eclipse 5]: phrase(chunk_list(Ret),[3,4,5,2,1,6,7,88,9,4,5,6,7,2,1,2,3]).

Ret = [[3, 5], 2, 1, [6, 7], 88, 9, [4, 7], 2, [1, 3]]
Yes (0.00s cpu)

[eclipse 6]: phrase(chunk_list([[2,4],A,[2,8],3]),[2,B,4,6,2,C,4,5,6,7,D,E]).

A = 6
B = 3
C = 3
D = 8
E = 3
Yes (0.00s cpu)
```